# crc16 algorithm from C++ to bash

Tags: bash, checksum, crc, crc16

I am trying to implement a CRC16 checksum in bash.  I'm porting from an existing piece of C++ code.  I'm almost there, but I am getting different answers.

I don't quite see why the checksums between the C++ code and the bash script are different.

Another set of eyes would be a big help.

Here is the C++ code:

```
uint16_t Encoder::checksum(std::string thestring)
{
    uint8_t d, e, f;
    uint16_t c, r, crccalc;
    c = 0xffff;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < thestring.length(); i++)
    {
        d = thestring[i];
        e = c ^ d;
        f = e ^ (e << 4);
        r = (c >> 8) ^ (f << 8) ^ (f << 3) ^ (f >> 4);
        c = r;
    }
    c ^= 0xffff;
    crccalc = c;
    return crccalc;
}
```

And here is my bash code:

```
function calc_crc16()
{
    string=$1
    while read -d "" -n 1 ; do astring+=( "$reply" ) ; done <<< "$string"

    cnt=${#astring[@]}
    c=0xffff

    for ((x=0;x<$cnt;x++)); do
        char=${astring[$x]}
        e=$(($c ^ $char))
        s=$(($e << 4))
        f=$(($e ^ $s))
        t1=$(($c >> 8))
        t2=$(($f << 8))
        t3=$(($f << 3))
        t4=$(($f >> 4))
        r1=$(($t1 ^ $t2 ^ $t3 ^ $t4))
        c=$r1
    done
    c=$c ^ 0xffff
    echo "checksum = $c"
}
```

Is it going to have something to do with the size of the ints?  I'm guessing there's not much I can do about that in bash.

I'm getting an actual number, but it doesn't match the C++, which I know works correctly.  does anyone see anything where I may be screwing things up?

Comment: write a quick test to see what max int is in C++ vs bash. Good luck.

Comment: I think the biggest question I have here is ***why***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok.  with Sorpigal's help, i've got a working version.

i suspect this could all be done within an awk script, which may run a lot faster.  i may try that next.

thank you all for the help.  i don't mean to steal the solution here, but i worked on it, and figure it is worth putting up.

anyway, here is a working version:

```
function calc_crc16()
{
    while read -r -d "" -n 1 ; do astring+=( "$REPLY" ) ; done <<< "$1"

    cnt=${#1}
    c=65535

    for ((x=0;x<$cnt;x++)); do
        char=$(printf '%d' \'"${1:$x:1}")
        e=$(((c ^ char) & 0x00FF))
        s=$(((e << 4) & 0x00FF))
        f=$(((e ^ s) & 0x00FF))
        r1=$(((c >> 8) ^ (f << 8) ^ (f << 3) ^ (f >> 4)))
        c=$r1
    done
    c=$((c ^ 0xffff))
    echo "checksum = $c"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First problem is near the top

```
while read -d "" -n 1 ; do astring+=( "$reply" ) ; done <<< "$string"
```

`$reply` is wrong, since you didn't specify a variable name for read the name is `$REPLY`.

Next error is at the end

```
c=$c ^ 0xffff
```

This should be

```
c=$(($c ^ 0xffff))
```

At least this way it will run without errors, correctness and appropriateness is something else.

Correctness issues: What if the input string has a space? This will break horribly. Always quote variable exapnsions

Change

```
char=${astring[$x]}
```

to

```
char="${astring[$x]}"
```

Strangely this rule is different inside `$(())` constructs. Your bit operations should reference variables without any `$` in these cases

```
e=$(( c ^ char ))
s=$(( e << 4 ))
f=$(( e ^ s ))
t1=$(( c >> 8 ))
t2=$(( f << 8 ))
t3=$(( f << 3 ))
t4=$(( f >> 4 ))
r1=$(( t1 ^ t2 ^ t3 ^ t4))
```

And later

```
c=$(( c ^ 0xffff ))
```

This will cause variables to be expanded and whitespace not to blow things up.

In general you should also pass `-r` to `read`, see `help read` for what it does.

Why make an extra copy of `$1` before processing it into an array? Using

```
while read -d "" -n 1 ; do astring+=( "$REPLY" ) ; done <<< "$1"
```

is sufficient.

It's probably not necessary to turn your input into an array before processing. Instead you can slice characters out of the string in your loop, which is closer to what the C++ version is doing. Replace

```
char="${astring[$x]}"
```

with

```
char="${1:$x:1}"
```

This is operating directly on the function paramter; since we're no longer making a copy of that we also need to get `$cnt` a different way

```
cnt=${#1}
```

But you really have even bigger problems than this, like the fact that a character isn't an integer in bash. To convert you must use the following syntax:

```
printf '%d' \'a
```

where `a` is the character to convert. Inserting this into the context of the script it would be

```
char=$(printf '%d' \'"${1:$x:1}")
```

Now we're getting somewhere, but I really must ask you to consider whether all of this is really worth it. Even if you can make it work, what do you gain?

Comment: thank you.  i fixed this.  i am getting an error with the "e=$(($c ^ $char))" line, because $char is the '$' character (from the string i am passing to it).  is there a way to keep it from throwing this error ? bash seems to be interpreting the string in an odd way.

Comment: @jasonmclose: See my edit for a few words on this and some other things.

Comment: i know the premise seems odd.  but i am working on some code that is sending data over a serial line, and i need to checksum the data using a specific CRC.  i don't control the receiving end code, so my checksum has to match.  if i can keep this in a script, we can better manage things in the field (dunno if we will even have gcc on these boxes).  i have a crc executable that works, and can fall back on it if need be.  for the most part, this is a good bash lesson for me.

Answer (score 3):

just for future reference, here is the awk script that i came up with.

this works just as fast as the C++ code i have, which is basically instantaneous.  the bash takes about 10 seconds to run for the same string.  the awk is much faster.

```
function awk_calc_crc16()
{
    output=$(echo $1 | awk 'function ord(c){return chmap[c];}
    BEGIN{c=65535; for (i=0; i < 256; i++){ chmap[sprintf("%c", i)] = i;}}
    {
        split($0, chars, "");
        for(i = 1; i <= length(chars); i++)
        {
            cval=ord(chars[i])
            e=and(xor(c, ord(chars[i])), 0x00FF);
            s=and(lshift(e, 4), 0x00FF);
            f=and(xor(e, s), 0x00FF);
            r=xor(xor(xor(rshift(c, 8), lshift(f, 8)), lshift(f, 3)), rshift(f, 4));
            c=r;
        }
    }
    END{c=xor(c, 0xFFFF); printf("%hu", c);}')
    echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shorter (and faster) version
changes:
- the while loop at the beginning is not needed
- r1 is not needed
- cnt is not needed
- use capital letters for bash variables
- one less "\" (backslash) in char=$(printf …
- removed leading 0s for 0xFF

```
function calc_crc16() {
  CRC=0xFFFF

  for ((X=0; X<${#1}; X++)); do
    CHAR=$(printf '%d' "'${1:$X:1}")
    E=$(((CRC ^ CHAR) & 0xFF))
    S=$(((E << 4)     & 0xFF))
    F=$(((E ^ S)      & 0xFF))
    CRC=$(((CRC >> 8) ^ (F << 8) ^ (F << 3) ^ (F >> 4)))
  done

  let CRC^=0xFFFF
  printf "0x%X\n" $CRC
}
```